# DataGridView autosizemode to displayed cells for all columns and then fill to the datagridview size

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2017

I would like to have my columns (which are generated from a Data Source) size to fit all cells and then fill the rest of the DataGridView. I am using the DataBindingComplete to Autosize the columns, so there shold not be any issues on that end, but after searching around I haven't found a way to fit, then fill if needed. Any help would be greatly appreciated! As requested, the code for the autosizemode is below.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(ByVal sender As Object,   ByVal e As DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DataBindingComplete
     DataGridView1.Columns(0).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
     DataGridView1.Columns(1).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
     DataGridView1.Columns(2).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
     DataGridView1.Columns(3).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
     DataGridView1.Columns(4).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
     DataGridView1.Columns(5).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
     DataGridView1.Columns(6).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
     DataGridView1.Columns(7).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells
     DataGridView1.Columns(8).Visible = False
 End Sub
```

Comment: Always show your code.

Comment: I can do that, but as of now, all the columns just fill into the size of the datagridview

Comment: Sounds like it's working then.

Comment: My goal is to have the columns first resize to fit the entirety of their cells and then fit to fill the datagridview with the remaining whitespace, as opposed to just uniformly resizing to fit the datagridview.

Comment: I want the columns first make all the cells fit into them, and then uniformly grow to fit the size of the datagridview. As of now they all just grow to fit the datagridview. This causes some of the longer columns to not be fully displayed while short columns to have extra space

Answer (score 0):

Don't set more that one column to DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill, it causes issues because all of the columns with Fill want to take the rest of the space at the same time. (I've had problems with that in the past.)

Set all of the columns to DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells (or a different non-Fill mode), and set only one of them to DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill so that that one will use the rest of the space.

**DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode Enumeration**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewautosizecolumnmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

```
Member Name                   Description
AllCells                      The column width adjusts to fit the contents of all cells in the column, including the header cell.
AllCellsExceptHeader          The column width adjusts to fit the contents of all cells in the column, excluding the header cell.
ColumnHeader                  The column width adjusts to fit the contents of the column header cell.
DisplayedCells                The column width adjusts to fit the contents of all cells in the column that are in rows currently displayed onscreen, including the header cell.
DisplayedCellsExceptHeader    The column width adjusts to fit the contents of all cells in the column that are in rows currently displayed onscreen, excluding the header cell.
Fill                          The column width adjusts so that the widths of all columns exactly fills the display area of the control, requiring horizontal scrolling only to keep column widths above the DataGridViewColumn.MinimumWidth property values. Relative column widths are determined by the relative DataGridViewColumn.FillWeight property values.
None                          The column width does not automatically adjust.
NotSet                        The sizing behavior of the column is inherited from the DataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode property.
```